# using javascript generator with babel and webpack

Tags: javascript, generator, babeljs, uglifyjs, polyfills

I trying to test the following js code:

```
function* foo(x) {
    var y = 2 * (yield (x + 1));
    var z = yield (y / 3);
    return (x + y + z);
}

const it = foo( 5 );

// note: not sending anything into `next()` here
console.log( it.next() );       // { value:6, done:false }
console.log( it.next( 12 ) );   // { value:8, done:false }
console.log( it.next( 13 ) );   // { value:42, done:true }
```

but I'm getting:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I followed this guide [link](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/#example) but I can make my webpack to build my code using generator. Here is my webpack:

```
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!geniuz)/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      plugins: [
        'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties',
        'babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        [
          'babel-plugin-transform-runtime',
          {
            helpers: true,
            polyfill: false, // we polyfill needed features in src/normalize.js
            regenerator: true,
          },
        ],
        [
          'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread',
          {
            useBuiltIns: true // we polyfill Object.assign in src/normalize.js
          },
        ],
        ['transform-regenerator'],
      ],
      presets: [
        'babel-preset-react',
        ['babel-preset-env', {
          modules: false,
          targets: {
            ie9: true,
          },
          uglify: true,
        }],
      ]
    },
  }],
})
```

I also tried:

```
['transform-regenerator', {
          generators: true,
        }],
```

Comment: If you try not to uglify, does the error go away. If yes..  Uglify struggles with some modern javascript.  2:options.. One compile down to es5 / uglify,.. or try using babel's own uglifyier.  Babili.

Comment: There should be more info about this error. For example which line. Your code and config look ok.

Comment: @Keith none works for me

Comment: @YuryTarabanko you are right, this the exact error: ERROR in ./src/routes/Home/components/HomeContainer.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (191:10)

  189 |
  190 |
> 191 |   function* foo(x) {
      |           ^

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
module: { 
        rules: [   
          {     
            test:/\.js$/,       
            exclude: path.resolve(__dirname,'node_modules'), 
            loader: 'babel-loader', 
            query: {presets: ['es2015']}  
          }  
        ]         
    }
```

Comment: Great but this is not an answer :) What do you think was wrong with OPs config?

Comment: according to docs initial definition of generators starting from ecmascript2015, i dont see this present in above config, may be this is cause of the issue, when i specify preset es2015 in my app generators starts to work this is all i know :)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Must add `@babel/transform-runtime` plugin to babel.config.js file look like below:

```
presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
plugins: [
  '@babel/transform-runtime',
  '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
  '@loadable/babel-plugin',
],
```